# Why does bit shifting a negative number doesn't work?

Tags: java, bit-shift, bitmask, bit-masks

Here is my code:

```
    long x1 = -123;
    long y1 = -312;
    long x2 = -111;
    long y2 = -112;
    long packed = x1 | y1 << 15 | x2 << 30 | y2 << 45;
    Debug.log("x1:" + ((packed) & 0b111111111111111));
    Debug.log("y1:" + ((packed >> 15) & 0b111111111111111));
    Debug.log("x2:" + ((packed >> 30) & 0b111111111111111));
    Debug.log("y2:" + ((packed >> 45) & 0b111111111111111));
```

I need x1, x2, x3, x4 to be up to 16384(2^14). So with added +- sign, it's total 15 bits. Why am I getting incorrect values?

Comment: @AndrewMorton why not? they have 15 ones, because the number is up to 14 bits(+1 for a +- sign)

Comment: Doh! Maybe I need to get glasses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mask off the bits you're interested in before packing the values together.  Most of the bits in -111 as a long are set and they're getting or'ed in with the other values you're packing.

Using a bitfield might be easier for you and you can let the compiler deal with all the masking and shifting for you:

```
struct packedCoords
{
    long long x1 : 15;
    long long y1 : 15;
    long long x2 : 15;
    long long y2 : 15;
};

packedCoords test;
test.x1 = -123;
test.y1 = -312;
test.x2 = -111;
test.y2 = -112;

printf("sizeof packedCoords = %d\n", sizeof(packedCoords));
printf("x1: %d\n", static_cast<int>(test.x1));
printf("y1: %d\n", static_cast<int>(test.y1));
printf("x2: %d\n", static_cast<int>(test.x2));
printf("y2: %d\n", static_cast<int>(test.y2));
```

Comment: I'm actually using java... I added the tag. And I don't need struct, I need bit masking.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it this way:

```
long packed = x1>0?x1:(-x1) | (x1>0?1:0) << 15;
long decodedX1 = (((packed) & 0b11111111111111));
if(((packed >> 14) & 0b1) == 0)
    decodedX1 = -decodedX1;
```

I know, looks nasty. We force it to be positive and then manually set a sign bit.

Answer (score 1):

I see you deduced (possibly from IronMensan's answer) that the extra set bits were the problem and need to be masked off.

As penance for my back-to-front comment, I wrote some code and generalised it a bit to reduce the use of "magic numbers". It's in C#, but that's quite similar to Java for this purpose:

```cs
long x1 = -345;
long y1 = 299;
long x2 = -111;
long y2 = -112;

int bitLengthToPack = 15;

long signBit = 1 << (bitLengthToPack - 1);
long dataBits = (signBit << 1) - 1;
long upperBits = ~dataBits;

long packed = (x1 & dataBits) | (y1 & dataBits) << bitLengthToPack | (x2 & dataBits) << (bitLengthToPack * 2) | (y2 & dataBits) << (bitLengthToPack * 3);

long x1e = packed & dataBits;

if ((x1e & signBit) > 0)
{
    x1e = x1e | upperBits;
}

Console.WriteLine("x1e: " + x1e);

long y1e = (packed >> bitLengthToPack) & dataBits;
if ((y1e & signBit) > 0)
{
    y1e = y1e | upperBits;
}

Console.WriteLine("y1e: " + y1e);

long x2e = (packed >> (bitLengthToPack * 2)) & dataBits;
if ((x2e & signBit) > 0)
{
    x2e = x2e | upperBits;
}

Console.WriteLine("x2e: " + x2e);

long y2e = (packed >> (bitLengthToPack * 3)) & dataBits;
if ((y2e & signBit) > 0)
{
    y2e = y2e | upperBits;
}

Console.WriteLine("y2e: " + y2e);
```

If you had a smaller range of values, you could reduce the value of `bitLengthToPack`. I couldn't think of a way to remove the conditionals from the unpacking; perhaps someone more ingenious than me could.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
long pack(long v, int shift) {
    return (v & 0b111111111111111) << (shift * 15);
}

long unpack(long v, int shift) {
    long r = v >> (shift * 15) & 0b111111111111111;
    if ((r & 0b100000000000000) != 0)
        r |= ~0b111111111111111;
    return r;
}
```

and

```
    long x1 = -123;
    long y1 = -312;
    long x2 = -111;
    long y2 = -112;
    long packed = pack(x1, 0) | pack(y1, 1) | pack(x2, 2) | pack(y2, 3);
    Debug.log("x1:" + unpack(packed, 0));
    Debug.log("y1:" + unpack(packed, 1));
    Debug.log("x2:" + unpack(packed, 2));
    Debug.log("y2:" + unpack(packed, 3));
```

generalized version:

```
long pack(long v, int width, int shift) {
    long mask = -1 >>> Long.SIZE - width;
    return (v & mask) << (shift * width);
}

long unpack(long v, int width, int shift) {
    long mask = -1 >>> Long.SIZE - width;
    long r = v >> (shift * width) & mask;
    if ((r & (1 << width - 1)) != 0)
        r |= ~mask;
    return r;
}
```

specify 15 for argument `width` in this case.

Comment: Ooh, a tidier version of what I came up with (I'm not suggesting your answer is derived from mine in any way by that, I'm sure it isn't). Do you feel like generalising it to allow for different ranges of values, i.e. removing magic numbers like 15 and those binary literals?